# Sources for Android 34, Android SDK Platform 34 and 2 more SDK components were not installed

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, installation, sdk

[image][image]

Preparing "Install Sources for Android 34 (revision 1)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sources-34_r01.zip
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Sources for Android 34: Tag mismatch!.
"Install Sources for Android 34 (revision 1)" failed.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 34 (revision 2)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-34-ext7_r02.zip
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Platform 34: Tag mismatch!.
"Install Android SDK Platform 34 (revision 2)" failed.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 34 v.34.0.0".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r34-windows.zip
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Build-Tools 34: Tag mismatch!.
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 34 v.34.0.0" failed.
Preparing "Install Android Emulator v.32.1.15".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows_x64-10696886.zip
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: Tag mismatch!.
"Install Android Emulator v.32.1.15" failed.
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Sources for Android 34: Tag mismatch!.
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Platform 34: Tag mismatch!.
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Build-Tools 34: Tag mismatch!.
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: Tag mismatch!.

Preparing "Install Sources for Android 34 (revision 1)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sources-34_r01.zip
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Sources for Android 34: Tag mismatch!.
"Install Sources for Android 34 (revision 1)" failed.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 34 (revision 2)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-34-ext7_r02.zip
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Platform 34: Tag mismatch!.
"Install Android SDK Platform 34 (revision 2)" failed.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 34 v.34.0.0".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r34-windows.zip
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Build-Tools 34: Tag mismatch!.
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 34 v.34.0.0" failed.
Preparing "Install Android Emulator v.32.1.15".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows_x64-10696886.zip
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: Tag mismatch!.
"Install Android Emulator v.32.1.15" failed.
Android Studio setup was canceled

I am trying to install new  android-studio-2022.3.1.19-windows but SDK is not installed and shows this of error again to again. how to solve this problem

How to solve this problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.